# TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning Node Js and express as ORM i need to create user authorization and i have managed to create signup backend code and tested it via postman and it work perfect, the challenge come with login, when i test it via postman i get an this error in my vscode terminal "TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined" I have tried to find out but many solution state there is a problem with sequelize order, that app.use(bodyParser.json()); should come first before routes and my order are correct but still a get the same error. please who can help me

My user (signup and login code)

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/users');
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/signup',(req, res, next)=>{
    User.findOne({
        where:{
            email:req.body.email
        }
    }).then(user=>{
        if(user){
            res.status(409).json({
                message:'Email alreadly exist!'
            })
        }else{
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash)=>{
                if(err){
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error:err
                    });
                }else{
                    const user =new User({
                        email:req.body.email,
                        password: hash
                    });
                    user.save()
                    .then(result=>{
                        // console.log(result)
                        res.status(201).json({
                            message:'User created successfully'
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error:err
                        });
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })

});

router.post('/login',(req, res, next)=>{
    User.findOne({
        where:{
            email:req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user =>{
        if(user.length<1){
            return res.status(401).json({
                message:'Authentication failed'
            });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result)=>{
            if(err){
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message:'Authentication failed'
                });
            }
            if(result){
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message:'Authorization granted!'
                });
            }
            return res.status(401).json({
                message:'Authentication failed'
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error:err
        });
    });
});
module.exports=router;
```

my app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app= express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');
const orderRoutes = require('./api/routes/orders');
const userRoutes =require('./api/routes/users');
const sequelize =require('./api/config/database');





app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

        if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT, POST, GET, DELETE');
            return res.status(200).json({

            });
        }
        next();//this allow our request to procede
});


app.use('/products',productRoutes);
app.use('/orders',orderRoutes);
app.use('/users',userRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    const error =new Error('Page Not Found');
    error.status=404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next)=>{
    res.status(error.status||500);
    res.json({
        error:{
            message:error.message
        }
    });
});
sequelize.sync().then(result=>{
    // console.log(result);
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
module.exports=app;
```

this is pc from postman[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Register and login routes

const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/users');
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/signup',(req, res, next)=>{
    User.findOne({
        where:{
            email:req.body.email
        }
    }).then(user=>{
        if(user){
            res.status(409).json({
                message:'Email alreadly exist!'
            })
        }else{
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash)=>{
                if(err){
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error:err
                    });
                }else{
                    const user =new User({
                        email:req.body.email,
                        password: hash
                    });
                    user.save()
                    .then(result=>{
                        // console.log(result)
                        res.status(201).json({
                            message:'User created successfully'
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error:err
                        });
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })

});


router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {


    console.log("req.body: ", req.body);

    try {
        if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
            console.log("Email and password not given");
            return res.status(400).send("Email and password is required");
        }

        const { email, password } = req.body;

        let user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
            console.log("user not found");
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication failed' });
        }

        const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!validPassword) {
            console.log("Password is not valid");
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication failed' });
        }

        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Authorization granted!' });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Err: ", err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }

});
module.exports=router;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is my db, model and server

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const PORT = process.env.PORT||4000;
const server =http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT);
```

user model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/database');
const User = sequelize.define('users',{
    id:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    email:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        required: true,
        notEmpty:true,
        validate:{
            isEmail:true,
        },
        unique:'email'

    },
    password:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        required: true
    }

});

module.exports=User;
```

db

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize =new Sequelize('projectone','root','',{
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost'
    });


    module.exports=sequelize;
```

this is user routes for signup and login

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/users');
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      let user = await User.findOne({where:{email}});

      if (user) return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Email already exist!' });

      user = new User({ email, password });
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
      await user.save();

      res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created successfully' });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    }
  });

  router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
      if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).send("Email and password is required");
      }

      const { email, password } = req.body;

      let user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

      if (!user) {
        console.log("user not found");
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
      }

      const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.get("password"));

      if (!validPassword) {
        console.log("Password is not valid");
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
      }

      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Authorization granted!" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Err: ", err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }
  });

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: it means that the request you are sending from POSTMAN or whatever frontend you are using are not sending payload in the POST request in /signup , can you show me the payload of form data you are sending ? it's saying your body is ```undefined```

Comment: Raju check the image i uploaded the user i have signup in my database with no problem, but when a login i get that undefined error

Comment: Could be one or couple of things. One is that your Sequelize didn't actually save password, another is that you're using `findOne` but use an array accessor, or that `req.body.password` is just `undefined`

Comment: Also, I have some edits. You need to `return User.findOne({...})` to use the result in the next Promise chain

Comment: Hey brother you don't need " where " just do  ```User.findOne({email:req.body.email })``` and also console.log(user) if error arises,

Comment: ionizer ,i have  uploaded a screen short of how you recommended but still I get last json message"Authentication failed hahahahah!"

Comment: Can you check my new edited answer?  I could make it work, the password can be retrieved from the user.get("password").

Comment: According to the docs, `user.get('password')` is the same as `user.password`... I think `.toJSON()` is the sure-fire way to properly get the data.

Comment: Did you see my messages in the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this login route, I converted code using async/await and handled all the possibilities, even the problem still exists it will give you all the information what is wrong.

note that after finding the user, password can be retrieved from **user.get("password")** like this:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      return res.status(400).send("Email and password is required");
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

    if (!user) {
      console.log("user not found");
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
    }

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.get("password"));

    if (!validPassword) {
      console.log("Password is not valid");
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed" });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Authorization granted!" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err });
  }
});
```

And your signup route can be refactored to async/await like this:

```
router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({where:{email}});

    if (user) return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Email already exist!' });

    user = new User({ email, password });
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created successfully' });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201571/discussion-on-answer-by-suleymansah-typeerror-cannot-read-property-password-o).

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and put some comments on it. Please try:

Signup route

```
router.post('/signup',(req, res, next)=>{
    return User.findOne({
        where:{
            email:req.body.email
        }
    }).then(user=>{
        if(user){
            res.status(409).json({
                message:'Email alreadly exist!'
            })
        }else{
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash)=>{
                if(err){
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error:err
                    });
                }else{
                    return User.create({
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: hash
                    })
                    .then(result=>{
                        // console.log(result)
                        res.status(201).json({
                            message:'User created successfully'
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error:err
                        });
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })

});
```

Signin route

```
router.post('/login',(req, res, next)=>{
    // .findOne does not return an array and you need to return this Promise to be chainable
    return User.findOne({
        where:{
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user =>{
        if(!user) { // User not found!
            console.log(`User with ${req.body.email} not found!`);
            return res.status(401).json({
                message:'Authentication failed'
            });
        }

        const u = user.toJSON();
        console.log('User data from DB:', u);
        // Changed `user[0].password` to `u.password`
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, u.password, (err, result)=> {
            if(err){
                console.error('Error during comparison!', err);
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message:'Authentication error'
                });
            }
            if(result){
                console.log('Authentication success!');
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message:'Authorization granted!'
                });
            }
            return res.status(401).json({
                message:'Authentication failed'
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error:err
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ionizer, it work the error has gone but when I send the request to login let me authentication fails seems like it is unable to compare, any help

Comment: Do you have any log of the new issue? Try logging `req.body.password` and `user.password`

Comment: i have  tried to debug my json message, so when i send a response i get the last message seems like login credential can not be compared

Comment: Actually, I modified the above code and added some loggings, can you please try again and see which log appears?

Comment: ionizer check the screen short i have uploaded, i still get the  last json message "Authentication failed hahahahah!"

Comment: One last thing we can try is to use `user.toJSON().password` to get the user data. If this doesn't work, then I'd recommend posting a new question on this as this could make the discussion a lot longer here. Please also make sure that you are using the same password when registering, just to avoid silly mistakes :p

Comment: Oh and also, 1 thing I totally forgot, please try using `User.create({email: '...', password: hash})` when creating a database entry